# Create resources via terraform in azure pipeline while create container instance

Tags: terraform

I am receiving an internal server error when trying to perform a ContainerGroupsCreateOrUpdate with a container instance. The Container Group Name is "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" and I am using containerinstance.ContainerInstanceClient. The error message reads: "Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code='InternalServerError' Message='Encountered an internal server error. The tracking activity id is 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', correlation id is 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.'" How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform output results give truncated error code.

1. Azure Portal -> Montior -> Activity log.
2. You can get the detailed error codes for that issue.

The issue should be resolved using below two steps,

1. Remove the creds in provider.
2. Use cli in ci-cd to login
3. The azure account logged in or service profile logged in should be cleared using

```html
az account clear
```

4. Now use you pipeline build.yml file to perform

```html
terraform apply --auto-approve
```